# TSQL COUNT show 0 when no row returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, count

I have one table, **Documents**, that lists all documents and various information about them.  What I'm trying to do is, for a select group of authors, get a count of all documents they've authored in the past year.  For each document, we have a column to store the Author name and ID.

I am currently getting what I want with the query below, but my problem is I also need to list all authors that haven't authored any documents.  (So, for the **Number of Docs Signed** column they'd have a zero value)  Here's what I have now:

```
SELECT 
[AuthorID] As "Author ID",
RTRIM([AuthorFirstName]) + ' ' + RTRIM([AuthorLastName]) AS "Author", 
COUNT(Document.ID) AS "Number of Docs Authored"

FROM Document

WHERE   [CompletedStatus] = 'Yes' 
AND     [AuthorID] IN (<list of author ID's>) 
AND     [CompletedOn] >= DATEADD(d, -365, getdate())


GROUP BY [AuthorID], [AuthorFirstName], [AuthorLastName]

ORDER BY [Number of Docs Signed] DESC
```

From reading around on SO I know I think I need some kind of subquery that I can join in order to show a '0' when there are no rows returned by COUNT.  But for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it.  I'm pretty sure it needs to be something like [this](http://lichao.net/eblog/how-to-display-0-in-conditional-group-by-report-in-count-sql-query-200808164.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from the Authors table and do a left outer join to the documents table. This means you need to move the criteria into the outer join...

```
SELECT 
[AuthorID] As "Author ID",
RTRIM([AuthorFirstName]) + ' ' + RTRIM([AuthorLastName]) AS "Author", 
COUNT(Document.ID) AS "Number of Docs Authored"

FROM 
    Author a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d on d.AuthorID = a.ID
        AND [CompletedStatus] = 'Yes' 
        AND [CompletedOn] >= DATEADD(d, -365, getdate())
WHERE
    a.ID IN (<list of author ID's>) 

GROUP BY a.[ID], [AuthorFirstName], [AuthorLastName]

ORDER BY [Number of Docs Signed] DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably if they haven't authored any documents, they're not going to have a record in the document table.
I guess you have an Authors table or similar?

Something like

```
SELECT 
a.[AuthorID] As "Author ID",
RTRIM(a.[AuthorFirstName]) + ' ' + RTRIM(a.[AuthorLastName]) AS "Author", 
COUNT(Document.ID) AS "Number of Docs Authored"
FROM Author a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
Document
ON A.AuthorId = Document.AuthorId
AND  [CompletedStatus] = 'Yes' 
AND     [CompletedOn] >= DATEADD(d, -365, getdate())
WHERE     A.[AuthorID] IN (<list of author ID's>) 
GROUP BY a.[AuthorID], a.[AuthorFirstName], a.[AuthorLastName]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an authors table, you would do:

```
SELECT  a.AuthorID As "Author ID",
        RTRIM([a.AuthorFirstName]) + ' ' + RTRIM([a.AuthorLastName]) AS "Author", 
        COUNT(Document.ID) AS "Number of Docs Authored"
FROM Authors a left outer join
     Document d
     on a.[AuthorID] = d.[AuthorID] and
        d.CompletedStatus = 'Yes' and
       [CompletedOn] >= DATEADD(d, -365, getdate())
WHERE a.[AuthorID] IN (<list of author ID's>) and
GROUP BY a.AuthorID, a.AuthorFirstName], a.authorLastName
ORDER BY [Number of Docs Signed] DESC
```

Note all the conditions on the document are going in the `on` clause.  Otherwise, the values will be NULL for the Authors with no documents.

If you don't have an authors table, you can create one on the fly:

```
with authors as (
    select <id> as id, <firstname> as authorFirstName, <lastname> as authorLastName union all
    select . . .
)
```

And then use the above query.  You need to fill in each author with the name information.

Comment: Yes, I do have an authors table.  With your first query, I tried it but it's giving me ALL our authors, instead of just the authors in the list.  Any ideas?

Comment: I just moved the authorID part of the `on` cluase back to a `where` clause.  That should fix the problem.