# Show "0" results with COUNT(course.id)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that correctly counts the number of students in each course within the platform, but it doesn't return results where the student count = 0. How do I modify the below query to include this?

**SQL:**

```sql
/*  MSSQL
    Name: Courses using the TDC themes with student enrolment count
    Description: Returns a list of courses using a TDC theme and the number of enrolled students in each course.
*/

select
    concat('<a target="_blank" href="%%wwwroot%%/course/index.php?categoryid=',cat.id,'">', cat.name,'</a>') as "Category",
    concat('<a target="_new" href="%%wwwroot%%/course/view.php?id=',course.id,'">',course.fullname,'</a>') as "Course",
    course.theme as "Theme",
    count(course.id) as "Students"
from prefix_course as course
    join prefix_context as context on context.instanceid = course.id
    join prefix_role_assignments as ra on ra.contextid = context.id
    join prefix_course_categories as cat on cat.id = course.category
where context.contextlevel = 50 and ra.roleid = 5 and course.theme like 'tdc%'
group by cat.id, cat.name, course.id, course.fullname, course.theme
order by cat.name
```

**Actual Result:**

```
| Category  | Course             | # of Students |
|-----------|--------------------|---------------|
| Baking    | Baking 101         | 7             |
| IT        | Intro to Excel     | 9             |
```

**Intended Result:**

```
| Category  | Course             | # of Students |
|-----------|--------------------|---------------|
| Baking    | Baking 101         | 7             |
| IT        | Web Programming    | 0             |
| IT        | Intro to Excel     | 9             |
| Chemistry | Chemical Reactions | 0             |
```

I've searched a few questions on SO already (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347890/tsql-count-show-0-when-no-row-returned)), but cannot translate the answer to my situation.

Comment: one of your table doesn't have matching data, try use left join on prefix_role_assignments

Comment: Protip: don't generate view-level data in SQL. In this case, you're generating HTML inside your SQL. Don't do this because it will make your code much less maintainable in the long-run - and what if you want to run your query from a non-web application? Point is: follow the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: @metal that won't work because you'd end up with a count if there is any record in prefix_course. But he's asking for instances where the count is 0. I'm not sure the question is quite well formed. OP - why would there be a record in prefix_course if you are expecting the id count there to be 0 (aka non existent)?

Comment: @kjmerf, ahh I see what you mean. I might have to re-think how I've created this query then. It initially started as a query w/o the student count (ie, just the category, course and theme information), which is a much simpler query in the database. Do you have any recommendations on how to do this? I'll add a sqlfiddle link to include the db schema and some dummy data.

Comment: With expected results and sample data it should be doable.

Comment: @dai, I'm not running this query at the database-level. I'm running it at the application level in the Moodle platform via the Configurable Reports plug-in - allows Moodle admins to create and run select statements against the database w/o the user needing access to the database itself.
https://moodle.org/plugins/block_configurable_reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time off this conundrum, I've realised my issue was with the selection of tables I thought was required to execute this task. I've resolved this question with the following `select` statement and tables. I've also used different dummy data (sorry), so I've updated my OP with the new dummy data:

```sql
select
    concat('<a target="_blank" href="%%wwwroot%%/course/index.php?categoryid=',cat.id,'">', cat.name,'</a>') as "Category",
    concat('<a target="_new" href="%%wwwroot%%/course/view.php?id=',c.id,'">',c.fullname,'</a>') as "Course",
    c.theme as Theme,
    sum(iif(r.id is null,0,1)) as '# of Students'
from prefix_user as u
    join prefix_role_assignments as ra on u.id = ra.userid
    left outer join prefix_role as r on ra.roleid = r.id and r.id = 5 -- student role id in moodle.
    join prefix_context as ct on ra.contextid = ct.id
    join prefix_course as c on c.id = ct.instanceid and ct.contextlevel = 50 -- 'course' context type.
    join prefix_course_categories as cat on cat.id = c.category and c.theme like 'tdc%'
group by cat.id, c.id, cat.name, c.fullname, c.theme
```

Tables:
prefix_course_categories:

```
|  id | name      |
|-----|-----------|
| 1   | Baking    |
| 2   | Chemistry |
| 3   | IT        |
```

prefix_course:

```
|  id | name               | categoryid  | theme        |
|-----|--------------------|-------------|--------------| -- prefix_course.categoryid =
| 8   | Baking 101         | 1           | tdcemuteal   | -- prefix_course_categories.id
| 90  | Web Programming    | 2           | NULL         |
| 287 | Intro to Excel     | 2           | tdcemuaqua   |
| 396 | Chemical Reactions | 3           | tdcemuorange |
```

prefix_user:

```
|  id  |
|------|
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 5    |
| 8    |
| 15   |
| 16   |
| 20   |
| 23   |
| 77   |
| 99   |
| 303  |
| 879  |
| 959  |
| 1235 |
```

prefix_role:

```
|  id | name                |
|-----|---------------------|
| 1   | Manager             |
| 2   | Course Creator      |
| 3   | Teacher             |
| 4   | Non-Editing Teacher |
| 5   | Student             |
```

prefix_role_assignments:

```
|  id |  contextid | userid | roleid |
|-----|------------|--------|--------| -- prefix_role_assignments.contextid = 
| 1   | 1          | 879    | 5      | -- prefix_context.id
| 2   | 2          | 303    | 5      | 
| 3   | 3          | 5      | 5      | -- prefix_role_assignments.userid = 
| 4   | 4          | 15     | 6      | -- prefix_user.id
| 5   | 5          | 57     | 5      |
| 6   | 6          | 23     | 5      | -- prefix_role_assignments.roleid = 
| 7   | 7          | 959    | 5      | -- prefix_role.id
| 8   | 8          | 99     | 5      |
| 9   | 9          | 879    | 5      |
| 10  | 10         | 303    | 5      |
| 11  | 11         | 5      | 5      |
| 12  | 12         | 15     | 5      |
| 13  | 13         | 57     | 5      |
| 14  | 14         | 23     | 5      |
| 15  | 15         | 959    | 5      |
| 16  | 16         | 77     | 5      |
| 17  | 17         | 1235   | 5      |
| 18  | 18         | 8      | 1      |
| 19  | 19         | 23     | 7      |
| 20  | 20         | 287    | 7      |
| 21  | 21         | 287    | 7      |
| 22  | 22         | 287    | 7      |
| 23  | 23         | 287    | 7      |
| 24  | 24         | 699    | 7      |
```

prefix_context:

```
|  id |  contextlevel | instanceid |
|-----|---------------|------------|
| 1   | 50            | 8          | -- prefix_context.instanceid =
| 2   | 50            | 8          | -- prefix_course.id 
| 3   | 50            | 8          |
| 4   | 50            | 8          | -- instanceid where contextlevel = 50 are courses that students enrol into.
| 5   | 50            | 8          |
| 6   | 50            | 8          |
| 7   | 50            | 8          |
| 8   | 90            | 8          |
| 9   | 50            | 287        |
| 10  | 50            | 287        |
| 11  | 50            | 287        |
| 12  | 50            | 287        |
| 13  | 50            | 287        |
| 14  | 50            | 287        |
| 15  | 50            | 287        |
| 16  | 50            | 287        |
| 17  | 50            | 287        |
| 18  | 60            | 287        |
| 19  | 50            | 396        |
| 20  | 20            | 287        |
| 21  | 60            | 287        |
| 22  | 10            | 287        |
| 23  | 80            | 287        |
| 24  | 50            | 699        |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you move the prefix_course table to a left outer join and use sum(if(course.id is null,0,1)) instead of sum it should work:

```
select
    concat('<a target="_blank" href="%%wwwroot%%/course/index.php?categoryid=',cat.id,'">', cat.name,'</a>') as "Category",
    concat('<a target="_new" href="%%wwwroot%%/course/view.php?id=',course.id,'">',course.fullname,'</a>') as "Course",
    course.theme as "Theme",
    sum(iif(course.id is null,0,1)) as "Students"
from prefix_context as context 
    inner join prefix_role_assignments as ra on ra.contextid = context.id
    inner join prefix_course_categories as cat on cat.id = course.category
    left outer join prefix_course as course on context.instanceid = course.id and course.theme like 'tdc%'
where context.contextlevel = 50 and ra.roleid = 5
group by cat.id, cat.name, course.id, course.fullname, course.theme
order by cat.name
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the issue - it displays the same dataset as count(course.id).

Comment: It will also show the records that have a count of 0, because of the use of left outer join. And in SQL Server the conditional is IIF not IF (or you can use case).

Comment: ah, my bad. Just thought IIF was a typo! 

I had to shift the second inner join to the end of the from to resolve 'The multi-part identifier "course.category" could not be bound.', but this still produces the exact same dataset as my 'actual result'.

Comment: Yes, you are right. As part of the where clause there was a "and course.theme like 'tdc%'". This basically was making the left outer join behave like a inner join. I've changed it and move it as part of the Inner join conditions.

Comment: Hey @cte6, I've posted a comment with the code that resolves this issue. Your sum solution helped a lot in getting there!

Answer (score 0):

By grouping this way: `GROUP BY ALL`. This is an alternative to cte6's answer.

Adjusted query:

```
select
    concat('<a target="_blank" href="%%wwwroot%%/course/index.php?categoryid=',cat.id,'">', cat.name,'</a>') as "Category",
    concat('<a target="_new" href="%%wwwroot%%/course/view.php?id=',course.id,'">',course.fullname,'</a>') as "Course",
    course.theme as "Theme",
    count(course.id) as "Students"
from prefix_course as course
    join prefix_context as context on context.instanceid = course.id
    join prefix_role_assignments as ra on ra.contextid = context.id
    join prefix_course_categories as cat on cat.id = course.category
where context.contextlevel = 50 and ra.roleid = 5 and course.theme like 'tdc%'
group by all cat.id, cat.name, course.id, course.fullname, course.theme
order by cat.name
```

Comment: Nice! This is progress, but it is now showing a lot of data that shouldn't be here - it shows about a 1000 records and not the intended result I added to the OP.